# Unable to execute SQL queries

Tags: mysql, perl

I have a bunch of DOIs separated by `'\n'` in a *.txt file. The perl script I have written should read each line of the file and execute a select query. However, the program is unable to execute the SQL query. Could you please help me fix the problem?

After execution I get the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near
>   'http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/1521-3757(20001103)112:21<3947::aid-ange3947>3.0'

The first line of the dois.txt file contains the following DOI:

```
`http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/1521-3757(20001103)112:21<3947::aid-ange3947>3.0.co;2-k`
```

Here's my code:

```
my $file = 'dois.txt';

open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $file)
   or die " Could not open file $file";
while (my $doi = <$fh>) {

chomp($doi);
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("select * from mytable where doi = ''$doi'';");
$sth->execute || die "failed to execute:\n ", $DBI::Errstr;
print $sth->fetchrow_array, "\n";

}
close FH;
$dbh->disconnect;
```

Comment: create a string and publish it from `"select * from mytable where doi = ''$doi'';"`

Answer (score 2):

You want to call `prepare` outside the loop so that the execution plan only has to be calculated once (i.e., faster). Also, in addition to only preparing the query once, you don't have to figure out how to quote values correctly if you use [placeholders/bind parameters](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#Placeholders-and-Bind-Values).

```
my $file = 'dois.txt';

open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $file) or die "Could not open file $file: $!\n";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare(q{select * from mytable where doi = ?});

while (my $doi = <$fh>) {
    chomp($doi);    
    $sth->execute($doi) || die "failed to execute:\n ", $DBI::Errstr;
    print $sth->fetchrow_array, "\n";
}

close $fh;
$dbh->disconnect;
```